# Any good replacment for chrome apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Since chrome apps will retire this year, is there any good replacement for it? I have a webclient which runs locally inside a chrome app with support of a cardreader for login to the webserver. Since all the hardware related things are managed inside the chrome app manifest and within the chrome api it is difficult to find a good replacement for this, any idea?

Comment: https://nwjs.io/blog/chrome-apps-support/

Comment: Thanks, li will try this out. Looks very promising

Comment: Already answered here (duplicate question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709000/where-to-go-when-chrome-packaged-apps-are-no-more/39712078#39712078